# What is the relationship $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$ called?

Tags: limits, functions, terminology, relations

For example, $y=x^2$ would be a quadratic relationship. Is there name for this relationship?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  It's a type of [Mobius transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation)

Comment: In terms of investigating properties of it, it might help to rewrite this as $y=\frac{x+0}{x+1}=\frac{x+1-1}{x+1}=1-\frac{1}{x+1}$.  In doing so, by changing variables letting $Y=y-1$ and $X=x+1$, this is simply the graph $Y=-\frac{1}{X}$, so it is a translation of a graph of inversely proportional variables.

Comment: Suggestion: we call it a "Fred relationship".

Comment: @Fred: I'd rather say a *dsantorojr* relationship.

Answer (score 0):

This is an homography. The general form is

$$y=\frac{ax+b}{cx+d}$$ with $ad-bc\ne0$ (guess why).